# svg shown in edge , not in chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg, jqvmap

i recently decided to develop opencart , the opencart dashboard has a global map for orders  i want to change the world map to the iran map
this map uses jquery and jqvmap

i changed the codes of the map and its changed.
but it **is not showing** in **chrome** or **firefox** !
but its **ok** in **edge** ...

i noticed that its a problem from the iran map file , this map svg has a problem that i cannot fix it

this is the link of the map , can you explain me how to fix this ? thanks

`https://github.com/10bestdesign/jqvmap/blob/master/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.iran.js`

Comment: The github link is a javascript file witn an object that should be used to build an svg, The only problem I see is that you have 2 pairs of width height attributes for the svg element. The problem may be inside the script you are using to transform the object in svg code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map itself seems to work. I'm using Chrome. Here's a codepen with the map:
https://codepen.io/invisiblegorilla/pen/zYzKQqK

```
$("#country_svg").vectorMap({"map": "iran_ir",});
```

This library and its maps are available on cndjs which is what is used in the Codepen to import the maps: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqvmap

You said you changed the map? How did you change it? If you can update your question with info on how you changed the file or a link to your changed file then maybe we can find the issue.

Comment: yesss ! that was a problem in the library that i used , i changed it and it worked , thanks a lot :D